# Node order not preserved sling post servlet

Tags: aem, sling, jcr

I am using sling post servlet to read a json and create a page. I have my json in the structured manner. But, the order in which the nodes are getting created under the page is not the same as json. Please let me know your suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Is any consequence that the nodes inside the page are in different order?